# Python's equivalent to PHP's strip_tags?

Tags: python, strip

Python's equivalent to PHP's strip_tags?

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: check this http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52281/

Comment: Thanks Gagandeep. You may post an answer and I will up vote it

Answer (score 42, accepted):

**There is no such thing in the Python standard library.** It's because Python is a general purpose language while PHP started as a Web oriented language.

**Nevertheless, you have 3 solutions:**

- You are in a hurry: just make your own. `re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', value)` can be a quick and dirty solution.
- Use a third party library (recommended because more bullet proof) : [beautiful soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is a really good one and there is nothing to install, just copy the lib dir and import. [Full tuto with beautiful soup](http://www.ghastlyfop.com/blog/2008/12/strip-html-tags-from-string-python.html).
- Use a framework. Most Web Python devs never code from scratch, they use a framework such as [django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) that does automatically this stuff for you. [Full tuto with django](http://www.djangofoo.com/45/strip-html-tags).

Comment: @Hank sorry for any confusion. This is no longer a good method, sadly.

Answer (score 16):

Using [**BeautifulSoup**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmltext)
''.join([e for e in soup.recursiveChildGenerator() if isinstance(e,unicode)])
```

Comment: You may want to let him know that it's a third party lib.

Answer (score 9):

```
from bleach import clean
print clean("<strong>My Text</strong>", tags=[], strip=True, strip_comments=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't find many builtin Python equivalents for builtin PHP HTML functions since Python is more of a general-purpose scripting language than a web development language. For HTML processing, [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) is generally recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I built one for Python 3 using the HTMLParser class. It is more verbose than PHP's. I called it the HTMLCleaner class, and you can find the source [here](https://github.com/cwallenpoole/PyFram-Tutorial/blob/master/wk8/fri/view/html.py) and you can find examples [here](http://www.allen-poole.com/wordpress/2011/10/cleaner-html-strip_tags-in-python/).

Answer (score 1):

There is an active state recipe for this,

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52281/

It's old code so you have to change sgml parser to HTMLparser as mentioned in the comments

Here is the modified code,

```
import HTMLParser, string

class StrippingParser(HTMLParser.HTMLParser):

    # These are the HTML tags that we will leave intact
    valid_tags = ('b', 'a', 'i', 'br', 'p', 'img')

    from htmlentitydefs import entitydefs # replace entitydefs from sgmllib

    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.result = ""
        self.endTagList = []

    def handle_data(self, data):
        if data:
            self.result = self.result + data

    def handle_charref(self, name):
        self.result = "%s&#%s;" % (self.result, name)

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        if self.entitydefs.has_key(name): 
            x = ';'
        else:
            # this breaks unstandard entities that end with ';'
            x = ''
        self.result = "%s&%s%s" % (self.result, name, x)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        """ Delete all tags except for legal ones """
        if tag in self.valid_tags:       
            self.result = self.result + '<' + tag
            for k, v in attrs:
                if string.lower(k[0:2]) != 'on' and string.lower(v[0:10]) != 'javascript':
                    self.result = '%s %s="%s"' % (self.result, k, v)
            endTag = '</%s>' % tag
            self.endTagList.insert(0,endTag)    
            self.result = self.result + '>'

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        if tag in self.valid_tags:
            self.result = "%s</%s>" % (self.result, tag)
            remTag = '</%s>' % tag
            self.endTagList.remove(remTag)

    def cleanup(self):
        """ Append missing closing tags """
        for j in range(len(self.endTagList)):
                self.result = self.result + self.endTagList[j]    


def strip(s):
    """ Strip illegal HTML tags from string s """
    parser = StrippingParser()
    parser.feed(s)
    parser.close()
    parser.cleanup()
    return parser.result
```

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't have one built-in, but there are an [ungodly number of implementations](http://www.google.com/search?q=python+strip+tags).

Comment: Actually I Googled with the same query you suggested but those didn't make me happy enough.

Answer (score -1):

Using beautifulsoup4,

```
def strip_tags(html_content):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')
    return soup.get_text()
```

- https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/
- https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/
- https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#get-text