# Deleting inline-code from html

Tags: django

I'm using the inline-app from Django-Basic-Apps for inserting images in Blogposts. But in some templates I don't want the images to appear. It's not enough to just not render them, I don't even want the inline-code to be in the html. Is there a way to delete the inline-code with a filter? I tried to use the "|cut" filter, but its just not flexible enough. I guess I would have to write my own templatetag to take care of this, but I'm quite new to Python and Django and don't now how that works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295942/pythons-equivalent-to-phps-strip-tags may be useful to you.

Comment: Looks very promising, I'm going to give it a try. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If anybody's interested, here is my solution:

```
@register.filter
def del_inlines(value):

    soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(value, selfClosingTags=['inline'])
    inlines = soup.findAll('inline')
    [inline.extract() for inline in inlines]
    return soup
```

BeautifulSoup is just great!