# string operation

Tags: python, regex, string

i have a string in which a word is like this `"#<i><b>when</b></i>"`. i want only word without any tag. when in striped `"#"` word became `"<i><b>when</b></i>"`. but when i striped `"<i>"` word became like "b>when"<b>when</b>"?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486/filter-out-html-tags-and-resolve-entities-in-python

Comment: And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295942/pythons-equivalent-to-phps-strip-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice it.

```
>>> '#<i><b>when</b></i>'[4:-4]
'<b>when</b>'
```

Comment: thanks but i want to keep record for tag that i removed... is any method or function which remove only tag

Comment: @Gautam: Slicing a string doesn't modify the string. If you assign the result of the slice to a variable, you'll keep the original tag and you'll have the word too.

Comment: if s = "#<i><b>when</b></i>", then s2 = s[:5] + s[8:19] + s[23:] should give what (I think) you want for this example.

Comment: I see 2 problems with this solution... (1) he said *without any tag*... I assume that includes `<b>`. And (2) It only works on this particular example.. although, of course, who knows what he's trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> s='#<i><b>when</b></i>'
>>> wordPattern = re.compile(r'\>(\w+)\<')
>>> wordPattern.search(s).groups()
('when',)
```

Comment: @Alex: Yeah, I read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454 and I only suggest it for this specific instance, not for general HTML parsing.

Comment: its great! but is there any way without regular expression?

Comment: @Zeak: ya its just for specific instance not for html parsing

Comment: @Gautam: Er... yes. See Ignacio's solution above.