# Python/Etree: Get text from element and its children

Tags: python, html, xml, parsing, elementtree

I've got to use some HTML like this:

```
<li><a href="#">S:</a><a class="#"> (n) </a><a href="#">trial</a>, <a href="#">trial run</a>, <b>test</b>, <a href="#">tryout</a> (trying something to find out about it) <i>"a sample for ten days free trial"; "a trial of progesterone failed to relieve the pain"</i></li>
```

The problem is that I need to get the text from both the children (like the `a`s and `i`s) and the text nodes (like the `,` parts between children).

**All I'm able to do is get the text from each child and put it together (which gives me everything but all the text nodes) OR get the just the text nodes (and not the `a` and `i`s). Is there a way to get both?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [lxml changelog](http://lxml.de/2.3/changes-2.3.html) shows lxml v2.3 is compatible with python 3.1.2 and newer.

Also you could use regexp `re.sub(r'<[^>]*?>', '', val)` as [Python's equivalent to PHP's strip_tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295942/pythons-equivalent-to-phps-strip-tags/2295954#2295954) said.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using lxml.html.

```
In [1]: import lxml.html

In [2]: el = lxml.html.fromstring('<li><a href="#">S:</a><a class="#"> (n) </a><a href="#">trial</a>, <a href="#">trial run</a>, <b>test</b>, <a href="#">tryout</a> (trying something to find out about it) <i>"a sample for ten days free trial"; "a trial of progesterone failed to relieve the pain"</i></li>')

In [3]: print el.text_content()
S: (n) trial, trial run, test, tryout (trying something to find out about it) "a sample for ten days free trial"; "a trial of progesterone failed to relieve the pain"
```

Comment: I need something Python 3 compatible. AFAIK, lxml isn't there yet.

Comment: From http://lxml.de/ The latest release works with all CPython versions from 2.4 to 3.2.